# Are there any desktop email clients that implement gmail style conversation view?

Tags: software-rec, mail-user-agent

I don't like threaded email views as much as the inline "[conversation view](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=5900)" of gmail, however gmail is not as fast as I'd like it to be. Are there any desktop clients which provide a "[conversation view](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=5900)"?

Comment: Does it have to have a GUI? Or can it be a console app?

Comment: @Gert: I don't know about xenoterracide, but I'd be interested in such a console app.

Comment: @Wolf what @alex said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get something along these lines via the [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) addon.  I haven't used it recently but when I did (a year or two ago) it was usable, though not quite as smooth as gmail itself.  It is being actively developed, so it has likely improved since then.  Reviews seem to be mostly positive, though it may not work with all versions of TBird.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [sup](http://sup.rubyforge.org/).  It is curses-based, so text mode only.